# What's the difference between ‘Zocker’ and ‘Hasardeur’?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

An article in *Süddeutsche Zeitung* is titled *[Seehofer ist ein Zocker, kein Hasardeur](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/bayern/csu-seehofer-ist-ein-zocker-kein-hasardeur-1.3150242)*. According to dict.cc and three other dictionaries, both *Zocker* and *Hasardeur* are translated as *gambler*. To make the title meaningful, however, there must be some difference between the two words. So, what is it?

Comment: Ein Fehler der Süddeutschen, die meint, das sei ein Unterschied.

Comment: @userunknown: Die beiden Wörter sind meiner Meinung nach nicht frei austauschbar. Irgendeinen Unterschied gibt es also wohl, auch wenn dieser vielleicht nicht primär in der Bedeutung und mehr im Registr liegt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *Zocker* is somebody who gambles. It does not say whether the gambling is particularly risky. It may be implied but not necessarily. There may be the occasional risky ‘all-in!’-bluff, but most of the time they’ll probably know what they’re doing.

A *Hasardeur* is directly connected to *hazard*. There is a much larger risk of things not going well for the gambler. To stick with the analogy of above, the risky ‘all-in!’s would be the rule, not the exception.

Thus, the title says something along the lines of

> Seehofer is a gambler, but he knows his limits.

Comment: Einen Spieler, der brav auf seine Limits achtet, würdest Du wirklich Zocker nennen? Hast Du Dich da nicht verzockt, und zu viel auf die Autorität der SZ gegeben?

Comment: I think that in the last 20 or 30 years saw a tremendous shift in the meaning of *Zocker* in colloquial language. Namely from something very close to *Hasardeur*, to something much less severe. Gamers may be to blame. Completely unreasonably, they started calling themselves *Zocker*.

Comment: @Ludi: Ich dachte es sei Konsens, dass sich Zocker hier eher nicht auf Computerspielzocker bezieht.

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt. Ich will nur die Gamer, auch allgemeiner, für die Bedeutungsverschiebung verantwortlich machen!

Comment: @userunknown In meinen Augen sind die drei Begriffe *Spieler – Zocker – Hasardeur* in der Reihenfolge Steigerungen voneinander. Und *All in* verträgt sich mE nicht wirklich mit *auf Limits achten* …

Comment: @Jan: Dass Du das als Steigerungsformen empfindest mag sein, ist aber aus Wörterbüchern nicht ableitbar, also vielleicht eine Geschmacksfrage oder ein Sprachgebrauch in Deiner Filterblase. Skatspieler, denen Begriffe wie All-in fremd sind, haben auch schon vor 100 Jahren Haus und Hof verspielt. All in heißt ja auch nur, dass man die liquiden Mittel, die auf dem Tisch liegen, alle riskiert werden, wenn ich richtig informiert bin. Das können auch 37 € sein, und auf dem Konto sind noch 30.000. All-in ist aber nicht gesucht, sondern Hazardeur vs. Zocker, und Adressat sind SZ-Leser.

Answer (score 6):

The Duden gives two different definitions for Zocker and Hasardeur:

**Hasardeur, der**

> jemand, der verantwortungslos handelt und alles aufs Spiel setzt

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hasardeur

**Zocker, der**

> jemand, der zockt

And here is the definition for "zocken":

> 1. (umgangssprachlich) Glücksspiele machen
> 2. (Jargon) (ein [Computer]spiel) spielen

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zocken

What I gather from that is they are similar, but that Hasardeur is someone who is willing to gamble it all (i.e. go all in) while Zocker is someone who is just reckless and/or careless.

Comment: Eine Person, die gelegentlich für einen Euro Lotto spielt, wird man schwerlich Zocker nennen. Aber Leute, die 1000 € wetten würden, dass wenn die SZ etwas schreibt, es auch einen Sinn haben muss, die findet man viele. :)

Comment: @userunknown: Der dritte Kommentar mit derselben Aussage.

Comment: Weil der Frager die Antworten wohl schon kennt, und nicht unbedingt nochmal die Kommentare liest, wie auch neue Leser der Frage, und die, die geantwortet haben, auch nicht unbedingt neue Kommentare zur Frage lesen oder zu anderen Antworten.

Answer (score 1):

A **Zocker** (in the traditional sense) takes high but very calculated risks (and he loves it).

A **Hazardeur** trusts his luck without thinking of the risks.